# Cygwin SSH - seteuid no such device or addresss

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I've setup Cygwin and want to ssh with domain user account on windows server 2012 R2. It works fine if I start the sshd service with "Local system account" but if I start the service with a `cygserver` local account or `domain\cygserver` then the service starts fine but when I try to ssh I see the message  `sshd: PID 1944: fatal: seteuid 1801: No such device or address`.

ssh in verbose mode on the client shows the following:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Some articles like https://blog.peterwurst.com/2016/09/15/ssh-server-on-windows-with-cygwin/ suggest to enable the following GPO with `cygserver` account in it. I tried them still the same error.

- Act as part of the operating system
- Create a token object
- Log on as a service
- Replace a process level token

I've verified `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` permission and the user home directory exists and also `passwd` file has the `/bin/bash shell` for the user.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know much about this issue, but this thread might also help you: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2019-03/msg00366.html

Comment: Already read those articles before posting here. Did a lot of research  but still couldn't find out the issue.

Comment: Just use "Local system account".

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and the solution was to start the **CYGWIN ntsec** servicem, before starting the CYGWIN OpenSSH service.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the subject user and SSHD account are not locked / disabled.

Confirm that password login works. PKI and password login take different paths to create a process token.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue in the log

```
seteuid XXXXXXXX: No such device or address
```

and this made the trick

```
passwd -R
```